# No command `LIST CONNECTIONS`?

Tags: orientdb

The doc2.1.x describe that the command `LIST CONNECTIONS` which can display all the active connections after connect the server. But I try v2.1.10, `!Unrecognized command`, and I find that the source code also doesn't have the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command will be introduced in version 2.2

[image]

For more information take a look at this link: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Console-Command-List-Connections.html